# ArFragment hides some views on Acitivity if add it programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, arcore

I have activity, where is located 2 fabs and text. I need to add ArFragment on full screen. If I add this fragment using xml, 2 fabs and text is shown. But if I use `supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.ontainer, ArFragment()).commit()`, after it is showing only 2 fabs and text disappears. How can I fix it, because I need to use programmatically way.

[image: Here you can see textView]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 1.0f)` for fixing problem